# How to transform row data in cassandra to nested json with respect to the columns

Tags: java, json, cassandra

I have the following table in cassandra. (row level data)

[image]

- The last column(ENGINE_CC) is unique. I want to categories the available data with respect to that column.

Required output in form of nested json:

```
{
"VECHILE_TYPE": [
    {
        "name": "Two Wheeler",
        "MODEL": [
            {
                "name": "Bike",
                "SUBMODEL": [
                    {
                        "name": "Super Bike",
                        "VECHILE_NAME": [
                            {
                                "name": "Suzuki_Hayabusa",
                                "Engine_CC": [
                                    "250",
                                    "300",
                                    "450"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "GSX",
                                "Engine_CC": [
                                    "225",
                                    "200"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Street Bike",
                        "VECHILE_NAME": [
                            {
                                "name": "Gixxer",
                                "Engine_CC": [
                                    "175",
                                    "150"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Four Wheeler",
        "MODEL": [
            {
                "name": "Economic",
                "SUBMODEL": [
                    {
                        "name": "Hatchback",
                        "VECHILE_NAME": [
                            {
                                "name": "I10",
                                "Engine_CC": [
                                    "1000",
                                    "1200"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Santro",
                                "Engine_CC": [
                                    "800",
                                    "900"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Could someone suggest

1)JAVA model for the nested json

2)How to add the row level data to the model

Is any library available to achieve this. This is basically a design question. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.